# Dipoles on Mathematica

Tags: plotting, physics

How would I plot a 2D field of a dipole but that has charge +q, and -q where they are on they y axis 4 units above and 4 units below the origin. and slice it along the xy plane? Any help on how you would do this?

Comment: Do you have an example of the style of plot you wish to achieve?

Comment: No I don't have a particular style as long as its a 2D slice in the xy plane

Comment: You could use [SliceVectorPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceVectorPlot3D.html?q=SliceVectorPlot3D)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that generates the three-dimensional electric field for a charge q located at position `{x0, y0, z0}`:

```
charge[q_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}][x_, y_, z_] := q/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2)^(3/2) {x - x0, y - y0, z - z0}
```

You can generate a three-dimensional vector plot:

```
VectorPlot3D[
    charge[1, {0, 4, 0}][x, y, z] + 
    charge[-1, {0, -4, 0}][x, y, z], 
{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

but to project it to the xy-plane is a little tricky

```
projector[{x_,y_,z_}]:={x,y}
VectorPlot[
    projector[
        charge[1, {0, 4, 0}][x, y, 0] +  
        charge[-1, {0, -4, 0}][x, y, 0]
    ], 
    {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

doesn't look that good.  Maybe someone can improve it.

[image: vector plot]

You can try `StreamPlot` instead.

```
StreamPlot[
    projector[
        charge[1, {0, 4, 0}][x, y, 0] +  
        charge[-1, {0, -4, 0}][x, y, 0]
    ], 
    {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: stream plot]